# Python AI Assistant needs more than one Input to get an output

Tags: python

I am trying to code my own AI Assistant. I've already finished the first and the second skill, but now my second skill needs two Inputs to get an output. The first one only needs one. When I add a third one it needs three times the Input. I have no idea what I can do against that. Can you help me? This is my code. I think the problem is in Line 33-38.

```
import pyttsx3
import datetime

engine = pyttsx3.init()
voices = engine.getProperty('voices')
engine.setProperty('voice', voices[1].id)  # changing index changes voices but ony 0 and 1 are working here

hour = datetime.datetime.now().hour
minute = datetime.datetime.now().minute
strtime = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M")


def say(text):
    engine.say(text)
    engine.runAndWait()


def wish_me():
    if 1 <= hour < 12:
        say("Hello and Good Morning")
        print("Hello and Good Morning")
    elif 12 <= hour < 18:
        say("Hello and Good Afternoon")
        print("Hello and Good Afternoon")
    elif 18 <= hour < 22:
        say("Hello and Good Evening")
        print("Hello and Good Evening")
    else:
        say("Hello and Good Night")
        print("Hello and Good Night")


if "Hello" in input():
    wish_me()

elif "time" in input():
    say(f"It is {strtime}")
    print(f"It is {strtime}")
```

Comment: Are you looking for boolean expressions? `if this or that`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ask for the input once and store it in a variable.

```
user_input = input("What would you like me to do? ")
```

Then use *that variable* in your `if...elif`

```
if "Hello" in user_input:
    wish_me()
elif "time" in user_input:
    say(f"It is {strtime}")
    print(f"It is {strtime}")
elif "something" in user_input:
    print("Something else")
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to implement a Natural Language Understanding engine. You need to separate your commands in command parameters. For example: Open [Application], Close [Application], Search [Content] on [Application], etc. Then  you'll need to implement a tokenization that looks for keywords related to command parameters, for example: When you say "Search [Content] on [Application]", you'll need to loop through the command and look for keywords, and in this example, the keyword "Search" is at the first index and if the keyword on exists, the command parameter is "Search [Content] on [Application]".

Then you'll need to implement a second tokenization, where you extract the variables of the command. If the command parameter is "Search [Content] on [Application]", you'll need to extract the command variables by using the keywords within this command parameter. In this example the "[Content]" variable is after the last index of "Search" and the "[Application]" variable is after the last index of "on".

An example of this approach could be found in an application written by me in C#: https://github.com/CSharpTeoMan911/Eva/blob/master/Eva%205.0/Natural_Language_Processing.cs

The project repository's main page: https://github.com/CSharpTeoMan911/Eva/tree/master

To see the application in action: https://sourceforge.net/projects/eva-ai/